# Why does my radio button event trigger when a different radio button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the following code to show "pers" and hide "bus" and vice versa

JQuery:

```
 $('input[name="perorbus"]').click(function() {
             if ($(this).attr('id') == 'bus') {
                $('#showbus').show();
                $('#showper').hide();
             }
             if ($(this).attr('id') == 'pers') {
                 $('#showper').show(); 
                 $('#showbus').hide();               
             } 

         });
```

HTML:

```
 <fieldset id="perorbus">
      <label style="font-size: large;">Personal Or Business?</label>
      <br/>
    <input type="radio" class="PerOrBus" value="pers" id="pers" name="perorbus"/>
    <label style="font-size: medium;">Personal Customer</label>
    <input type="radio" class="PerOrBus" id="bus" value="bus" name="perorbus"/>
    <label style="font-size: medium;">Business Customer?</label>
      <br/>
  </fieldset> 


<table id="showper">
    <tr>
    <td>Show Personal</td>
    </table>

    <table id="showbus">
    <tr>
    <td>Show Business</td>
    </table>
```

Any other Radio button that I put on the page triggers this. They are all given a name attribute like the following:

```
<fieldset id="CACCc">
   <input type="radio" id="1b" class="2b" value="4b" name="1b"/> Yes 
   <br/> 
   <input type="radio" id="id12" class="4class" value="4c" name="id12"/> No ​ 
   <br/></fieldset>
```

However, I have to assign the name on doc ready with jquery like the following:

```
     document.getElementById("1b").setAttribute('name', '1b');
     document.getElementById("id12").setAttribute('name', 'id12');
```

This is due to me being limited to not using name attributes in the HTML (long story)

Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: Can you reproduce this one on a fiddle ? (https://jsfiddle.net/k7knjypu/ works fine)

Comment: true, must be an issue somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Try going by the radio button and then the name of the radio button. Also use the change trigger. By the way, your fieldset has the same name. That could be an issue.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Update names
    $('input[type=radio][name=perorbus]').change(function() {
         if (this.id == 'bus') {
            $('#showbus').show();
            $('#showper').hide();
         }
         if (this.id == 'pers') {
             $('#showper').show(); 
             $('#showbus').hide();               
         } 
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still hides either one. Basically if either Pers or bus is selected and I choose another radio button, it minimizes whatever is selected regardless

Comment: It's probably in my code somewhere but I've too much to put up here

Comment: @Stacker Just be aware of all your names. Somewhere you have overlap.

Comment: @Stacker Also, make sure you update the names of your radio buttons before creating the triggers.

Comment: Yeah, it's the very first thing I do, I'll change all the names and try again

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my issue specifically is that is was a Sharepoint caching issue. Because I do not have access to remove cache, I simply renamed and re-id'd everything and got it working.

This will not solve other peoples issues, probably but the other answers should.